# need to show child hover menu as horizontal from it's main parent container

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to show child hover menu as horizontal from it's main parent container like this site http://www.batiosec.ma/

1. "Menu 3" width will be same as left & right li.
2. show child hover menu as horizontal from it's main parent container.

My code is below :
HTML

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-right">
         <ul>
             <li><a href="">Menu 1</a></li>
             <li><a href="">Menu 2</a></li>
                         <li class="dropdown"><a href="">Menu 3</a>
                                 <ul>
                                     <div class="dropmenu">
                                         <li><a href="">Level 1</a></li>
                                         <li><a href="">Level 1</a></li>
                                         <li><a href="">Level 1</a></li>
                                         <li><a href="">Level 1</a></li>
                                         <li><a href="">Level 1</a></li>
                                         <li><a href="">Level 1</a></li>
                                         <li><a href="">Level 1</a></li>
                                     </div>
                                 </ul>
                         </li>
             <li><a href="">Menu 4</a></li>
             <li><a href="">Menu 5</a></li>
         </ul>
     </nav>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #fafafa;
}
ul li {
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
}
ul li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #113333;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    padding: 10px 40px;
    text-align: center;
}
ul li a:hover {
    background-color: #4d4d4d;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
    ul li ul {
    display: none;
}
```

JQUERY:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

  $("ul li.dropdown").hover(
    function () {
        $("ul li ul").show(100);
    },
    function () {
        $("ul li ul").hide(100);
    }
  );

});
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is a way for doing this :

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $("ul li.dropdown").hover(
        function () {
            $("ul li ul").show(100);
        },
        function () {
            $("ul li ul").hide(100);
        }
    );
});
```

```css
ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #fafafa;
}
ul li {
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
}
ul li a {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #113333;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    padding: 10px 40px;
    text-align: center;
}
ul li a:hover {
    background-color: #4d4d4d;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
ul li ul {
    display: none;
}
.dropmenu {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-right">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">Menu 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Menu 2</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown"><a href="">Menu 3</a>
                    <ul class="dropmenu">
                        <li><a href="">Level 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Level 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Level 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Level 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Level 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Level 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Level 1</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="">Menu 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Menu 5</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```